# Using SSIS variable (@[User::FileName]) as part of UPDATE in `Execute Sql Server Task'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis, bids

We have an `SSIS` project that reads from a text file and inserts to a `sql server` table.

The `Flat File Connection Manager` for the `Flat File Source` uses a variable value as `ConnectionString` property. So essentially, it's *expression* `ConnectionString = @[User::FileName]`. This is working fine, and it's reading the file from the variable into the table.

Since the filename needs to be saved into the table, we need to also insert the filename into the table that's already storing the contents of the actual file. Currently, each line in our text file has 5 comma-separated value that we read into table `[TableFile]`, which also has 5 columns.

The change would be that `[TableFile]` will now have an additional column `[FileName]`. Therefore, the `Data Flow Task` that runs and inserts the contents of the file will also insert the filename (already saved in variable `@[User::FileName]`).

Since the table will always have one filename, I was thinking of somehow using an `Execute Sql Server Task` item to update the table with this value. But I have no idea of how to include the value of `@[User::FileName]` in the `SQL UPDATE` statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another SSIS variable to build and hold your entire UPDATE sql string, using the FileName variable to build that part of the string.

Then in the Execute SQL task, set SQL Source Type to "variable", and choose your SQL String variable as the Source Variable property.

Comment: I never thought of that. I'm having trouble with the actual update, but that's a whole new problem and I can post a question about that. Thanks.